# Selenium opens Multiple windows while working with pop-up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario is that I need to fill one form and click on a button, as soon as I clicked on the  button, one new pop-up should display.
Now my problem is that when I click on a button; 3 or 4 blank windows are opening.

Script just before the error is as follows:

`//To click on "Check Availability" Button
        waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCheckAvailbility")));
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCheckAvailbility")).click();
        sleep(4000);`:

Notes:

1. When I try to execute manually it works fine
2. When I run the same script by using Firefox it works fine but unfortunately I have to test this application only on IE.
3. I properly declared the "IEDriverServer.exe", so that is not an issue.

So ...friends any help or thought on this issue ???

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After much brainstorming I found that if we upgrade our Operating system to Windows 7 then this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... 
seems a lil bit strange because you press on the button once.
I would recommend you this one approach of handling new windows after button press:

```
   //Store the current window handle
        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

        //Perform the click operation that opens new window

        //Switch to new window opened
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }

        // Perform the actions on new window

            //Close the new window, if that window no more required
    driver.close();

        //Switch back to original browser (first window)

        driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

        //continue with original browser (first window)
```

Comment: Thanks eugene.polschikov, by modifying the code provided by u, we are able to resolve the issue in FF, but in IE the same issue is occurring. and one more additional issue is that, now the popup window is showing login window..any thought ??